# Non-concatenating file sink in Spring-XD?

Tags: file, spring-xd, sink

In Spring-XD the *file* **source** detects new files in an input directory and streams their content through the pipeline.

Is there an analogous **sink** which creates separate result files in an output directory (e.g. with the original file names) and not a single file to which all results were appended, http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#file-sink: "The file sink uses the stream name as the default name for the file it creates, and places the file in the /tmp/xd/output/ directory."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll down to the options in that document you referenced.

Use `--nameExpression=...`.

If you are using `mode=contents`; the original file name is available in the `file_name` header:

```
--nameExpression=headers[file_name]
```

`mode=lines` doesn't currently capture the file name (it will be fixed in the next release).

If you are using `mode=ref`, you need to set a header.

Comment: When i try to create a file-to-file pipeline by 'stream create --name test --definition "file --mode=contents | b:file --nameExpression=headers[file_name]" --deploy'
with spring-xd-2.0.0.BUILD-20150706.070103-39-dist, i get the following exception on the server side: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'dirExpression' in string value "${dirExpression}"

Comment: I added a working example with an additional parameter --dirExpression above. BTW: very nice software, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Minimal Working Example**

In Spring-XD

```
stream create --name test --definition "file --mode=contents | b:file --binary=true --dirExpression='''/tmp/out''' --nameExpression=headers[file_name]" --deploy
```

than

```
echo "1111"  >  /tmp/xd/input/test/file1.txt
echo "2222"  >  /tmp/xd/input/test/file2.txt
```

results in

```
ll  /tmp/out/
>  
>  -rw-rw-r--  1 rmv  rmv      5 Jul  7 10:19 file1.txt
>  -rw-rw-r--  1 rmv  rmv      5 Jul  7 10:19 file2.txt
```